# where to learn Trigger Development for IBM® OpenPages® GRC Framework

Tags: java, openpages

I've been asked by my company to learn Trigger Development for IBM® OpenPages® GRC Framework.

I have read the [Trigger Developer Guide](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/data/cognos/documentation/openpages/en/7.0.0/Trigger_Developer_Guide.pdf) provided by IBM. But it is more focused on only concepts but does not tell how to start (meaning setting a Development Environment).

I have no idea where to start and there is no help on the internet. Any help how should I start learning trigger development.

Comment: so if you can't answer or don't know about it, you're just gonna down-vote and vote to close...

Comment: is it a proprietary framework? I can't find any developer guide for even IBM openpages development

Comment: sort of... logically you are supposed to use Fujitsu Workflow Studio but we (like many others) are discarding Fujitsu WF Studio because its a Third-Party Tool and has problems with no possible way of debugging... so what we are trying to do is modify the Triggers by means of coding(in Java), it is not a new thing, it's being done. We just dont know how to do it...

Comment: IBM acquired OP in 2010 or so, so things are new and not well documented "yet".

Comment: Have you tried contacting IBM support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was trained in my company from an IBM consultant about IBM® OpenPages® GRC Framework. However, it seems to me that there are at this point in time no "free/open" guides available.

One of the "open" guides is the [paper](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/data/cognos/documentation/openpages/en/7.0.0/Trigger_Developer_Guide.pdf) you already pointed out. However, IBM provides a lot of trainings and also support for the IBM® OpenPages® GRC Framework, therefore I would suggest you contact, their  [customer support](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/openpages-grc-platform) or ask in your company about to get training on this framework.

Hope I could help!

BR.